# Can you view a friendship relationship's data (the "You and a friend" page) via the Facebook API?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get friendship details in Facebook Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874014/how-can-i-get-friendship-details-in-facebook-graph-api)

Is it possible to use Facebook's API to programmatically retrieve the "friendship details" data that shows up on the new "friendship" pages? (The pages that show the shared history of two users. The URL looks like: `www.facebook.com/[user1]?and=[user2]`).

The [graph api doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api) page doesn't list a "friendship" as one of the objects in the API specs so I am thinking it's not possible, or at least not yet documented.